# Issue in load(); on click

Tags: jquery, menu

This post is related to two other posts of mine. I thought that the last one would solve my issue, but it didn't as it actually uncovered another problem (my fault for not mention it on the first place).

My problem is with this code:

```
// Loading content upon click
$('#aEmpresa').click(function(e) {
    $('#mainContent').load('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14193826/aEmpresaContent.html #aEmpresaContent');
    return false;
});
$('#aNossaArte').click(function(e) {
    $('#mainContent').load('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14193826/aNossaArteContent.html #aNossaArteContent');
    return false;
});
$('#contactos').click(function(e) {
    $('#mainContent').load('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14193826/contactosContent.html #contactosContent');
    return false;
});
```

... only, there's something wrong with it. If you comment the entire "// Loading content upon click" part you'll see the menu working great.
I need help correcting this.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4jYb/)

Pedro

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: you can't load content's from different domain

Answer (score 1):

As Mohammad Adil said, this is due to the cross domain policy in client side scripts.

You can, however do this with php

```
echo file_get_contents("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14193826/aEmpresaContent.html");
```

Using PHP, you could place each page into a seperate div, and then use jQuery to show or hide the div with the appropriate content in.